# Changing visibility of buttons wrapped in a scrollview with onClick

Tags: android, scrollbar

I am using a ScrollView in an android app that has 10 buttons in total of which 1 button is  named "more". On the screen 5 buttons are displayed and the other 5 are not. I want that on the click of the "more" button the 5 invisible buttons should be displayed. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put all 10 buttons inside your scrollView. 5 of them would be normal and the other 5 set to `android:visibility="gone"` .

In your "more" button onclicklistener, set their Visibility to `button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

ScrollView will wrap its contents height nicely.

Comment: it is working but I want that when more button is clicked all the buttons which are not currently being displayed on the screen should get displayed.  that is the scroll bar gets scrolled....

Comment: you can scroll the scrollview by code. 

"yourscrollview.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);"

Answer (score 2):

There would be `LinearLayout` as container of the `Button` inside `ScrollView`.
Get that container and do something like.

```
public void onMoreClicked(View b)
{
    for(int i= 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("Button "+i);
        container.addView(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is `LinearLayout` inside `ScrollView` tag
`<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<ScrollView>`

Comment: Its not working it is giving me error    The method add(ImageButton) is undefined for the type LinearLayout

Comment: try `addView()` instead `add()`